# Mysql real escape

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

So am using the `mysql_real_escape_string` function to stop sql injection attacks in the following code but it doesn't seem to be working, how will i go about fixing this?

```
<?php
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bitcoinaddress']);

$btc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['btcamount']);

$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phonenumber']);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","db user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO `db_name`.`form` (`bitcoinaddress`, `btcamount`, `phonenumber`) VALUES
('$_POST[bitcoinaddress]','$_POST[btcamount]','$_POST[phonenumber]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  echo ($_POST['btcamount']);
  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: first debug your code with out using mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` does not change the variable whose value you have passed to it. You’re still using the unchanged `$_POST` values.

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated. The best way to prevent sql injection is by using PDO.

Comment: First, stop using `mysql_query`.  It's 2014, and less crappy APIs have been out for going-on a decade.  If you were using PDO or mysqli with a prepared statement, it would take care of the escaping *for* you.

Comment: I was wondering if you were kidding. Guess not. $phone is not used in the query. Also, use PDO.

Comment: I am relatively new at this, am still learning my basics.

Comment: You should learn basics about programming before jumping to databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't using it...

Make this change.

```js
<?php
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bitcoinaddress']);

$btc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['btcamount']);

$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phonenumber']);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","db user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO `db_name`.`form` (`bitcoinaddress`, `btcamount`, `phonenumber`) VALUES
('".$address."','".$btc."','".$phone."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  echo ($btc);
  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating variables with the escaped values but then going on to use the original variables.

But it's not a good idea to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` like this anyway as it won't always correctly sanitize the data without additional work such as checking that numeric input is actually numeric. Use `mysqli` or `pdo` and prepared statements instead.